# Sorting D3.js bar chart multiple ways (ascending and descending)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/txvuf14k/) is a fiddle of my code.

I'm trying to sort a bar chart in either ascending or descending order, after randomly refreshing the data feeding the chart.  When I click my 'Update Data' button and then click either of the sort buttons, it works fine.  But then when I click the other sort button (or even the same one again!), I get seemingly random results.

I think its because the data isn't being sorted itself, so maybe when each subsequent 'sort' click event happens, that event is agnostic to the sorting that happened before???

Yet I thought binding the data to the DOM elements took care of that issue?

Here is my sort function:

```
var sortBars = function (type) { 

        y.domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.value; }),
             d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.value; })])
         .range([Math.floor(height*0.2), height*0.8]);

        sortItems = function(a, b) {
            if (type == 'asc') {
                return a.value - b.value;
            }
            else if (type == 'desc') {
                return b.value - a.value;
            }
        }

        var delay = function(d, i) {
                return i * 50;
            }

        svg.selectAll('.bar')
            .sort(sortItems)
            .transition()
            .delay(delay)
            .duration(1000)
            .attr('x', function(d, i) {
                return x(i);
            });

        svg.selectAll('.label')
            .sort(sortItems)
            .transition()
            .delay(delay)
            .duration(1000)
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            })
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('x', function(d, i) {
                return x(i) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
            })
            .attr('y', function(d) {
                return height - y(d.value) + margin.top;
            });

        x.domain(dataset.sort(sortItems)
            .map(function(d) { return d.key }));

        svg.select('.axis')
                .transition()
                .delay(delay)
                .duration(1000)
                .call(xAxis);

};

d3.select('.sort-asc').on('click', function() {
        sortBars('asc');
});
d3.select('.sort-desc').on('click', function() {
        sortBars('desc');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of calling `x(i)`, you want to call `x(d.key)`, because you're creating the ordinal domain out of the keys.

Next, setting `x.domain(...)` to the re-sorted array is good, which is why your xAxis is updating correctly. However, you're doing it too "late", near the end of the function. Since you want the domain re-sorting to also affect the result returned by `x(d.key)`, you need to move that line so it happens before you update the bars and labels.

I'm pretty sure you can remove the calls to `sort(sortItems)` on the bars and labels, since the updates you're doing don't depend on `i` within the selection.

Finally, for style points, you can use d3 to define the sort functions like so (taking advantage of `d3.ascending(a.value, b.value)` and `d3.descending()`:

```
    var sortItems = function(a, b) {
        return d3[type == 'asc' ? 'ascending' : 'descending'](a.value, b.value)
    }
```

Or, if you pass `"ascending"` or `"descending"` as the `type` param:

```
    var sortItems = function(a, b) { return d3[type](a.value, b.value) }
```

Comment: Moving `x.domain(...)` up higher and changing `x(i)` to `x(d.key)` did the trick.  That makes total sense. Also, the built-in d3 sort functions are very useful too.  Thanks!